# Only one variable out of 2 gets passed through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to pass 2 variables through AJAX. 
But right now only one of them gets passed and saved in my database.

$image_id gets passed.

$uid doesn't get passed.

```
<div class="interaction"><a href="#" class="like" id="<?php echo $image_id ?>"
xml-id="<?php echo $uid ?>"><?php echo number_format($image_likes) ?></a>
</div>    


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".like").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var uid = $(this).attr("uid");
var dataString = 'id='+ id +'&uid=' + uid ;

var parent = $(this);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "like.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(html)
{
parent.html(html);
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

like.php:

```
if(($_POST['id']) && ($_POST['uid'])) {
$image_id=$_POST['id'];
$user_id=$_POST['uid'];
*some mysql query*
```

What am I'm missing here?

ps: I tried the SQL query with some dummy values and it works fine.

Comment: There is no `uid` attribute but `xml-id` attribute. See this : `var uid = $(this).attr("uid");`

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed it, i got mixed up when I typed my question.

Comment: You should use `isset()` function in your if statement to check if the variables are present or not. `if(isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['uid']))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your anchor:

```
<a href="#" class="like" id="<?php echo $image_id ?>" xml-id="<?php echo $user_id ?>">
```

To:

```
<a href="#" class="like" id="<?php echo $image_id ?>" data-uid="<?php echo $user_id ?>">
```

And then grab the value for user_id like:

```
var uid = $(this).data("uid");
```

You can use the network tab of the web inspector in Chrome to see what parameters are actually getting passed to your server.

Answer (score 2):

use the below code to pass multiple parameters in ajaxrequest

```
parameters: {parametername1:value1,parametername2:value2},
```

then get them in php

```
if(($_POST['parametername1']) && ($_POST['parametername2'])) {
$image_id=$_POST['parametername1'];
$user_id=$_POST['parametername2'];
*some mysql query*
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an attribute named "uid" in your markup.